# How to make a web service to send data via url in mongodb via loopback?

Tags: web-services, loopbackjs

In fallowing model I'd like to make a web service to send and save data to database something like.

```
localhost:3000/api/shops/shopname=cafe del mar&tel=123456&latlng=50.35;56.44&personId=1729451234
```

shops model

```
{
 "shopname": "string",
 "tel": "string",
 "latlng": "string",
 "address": "string",
 "id": "string",
 "personId": "string"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's odd to send data via Get request, but if you have considered the security concerns, you may Follow these steps:

1. Define a remote method:

   ```
   Shop.remoteMethod('createNewShop',{
       accepts: [{arg: 'shopname', type: 'string'},
       {arg: 'tel', type: 'string'},
       {arg: 'latlng', type: 'string'},
       {arg: 'address', type: 'string' }, 
       { arg: 'id', type: 'string'}, 
       { arg: 'personId', type: 'string' } ],
       returns: {arg: 'result', type: 'string'},
       http: {path: '/create-new-shop', verb: 'get'}
   });
   ```
2. Implement the createNewShop function in your shop.js file:

   ```
        var app = require ("../../server/server");
   Shop.createNewShop =function(shopname, tel, latlng, address, id, personId, cb){

   var instance = {
       shopname: shopname,
       tel: tel,
       latlng: latlng,
       address: address,
       id: id,
       personId: personId
   }
   var shop = new app.models.Shop(instance)
   shop.save().then(function(savedShop,err){
       if(err)
           throw err
       else
           cb (null, "done!")
   });
   }
   ```
3. Now you can call http://localhost:3000/api/shops/create-new-shop?shopname=cafe%20del%20mar&tel=123456&latlng=50.35-56.44&personId=1729451234
   Note that semicolon is a reserved char, so you can't use it as a value for your parameter and you should replace it with another char.

Comment: tnx, but it shows the fallowing error:.
Error
404 Unknown "shop" id "create-new-shop".
status: 404
code: MODEL_NOT_FOUND
Error: Unknown "shop" id "create-new-shop".

Comment: Change the name of your "id" attribute. Loopback has default primary-key attribute named "id". Maybe they are interefering with each other. Please let me know if the problem solved.

Comment: I think it is related with `var shop = new app.models.Shop(instance)` because in explorer it shows : ` "message": "app is not defined",
    "stack": "ReferenceError: app is not defined\n `. In server.js app is defined.

Comment: Ok, got it. You should define app variable in your shop.js file. var app = require ("../../server/sever")

Comment: @tashakori why do you used get verb instead of post. is that create()/insert?

Comment: @Parsaria as I mentioned in the first line of my answer "It's odd to send data via Get request, but if you have considered the security concerns, you may Follow these steps:". our friend Reza needed that way, that's why i used the "get" method, so that he could put the parameters in the url.

Comment: @tashakori You mean that this way is more secure than other possible  ways? i know you have not enough time but could you give a en example for my question?please.

Comment: @Reza it's useful to have a look at the first answer of this question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33837/get-vs-post-which-is-more-secure